# Outlook 2007 does not remember the password to my email account

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, passwords

I've setup Outlook 2007 at home to connect to my work exchange email via [Outlook Anywhere](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179036(office.12).aspx).  It works fine.  The only only annoying thing is that it does not remember the password despite the fact that I click on the Remember Password checkbox.

How can I make it remember the password.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type `regedit` in the Open box, and then press
>    <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> 2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\`
> 3. In the right pane, double-click `LmCompatibilitylevel`.
> 4. In the Value data box, type a value of `2` or `3` that is appropriate for your environment<sup>1</sup>, and then click OK.
> 5. Quit Registry Editor.
> 6. Restart your computer.

­

> <sup>1</sup> **LmCompatibilitylevel Values**
>
> `2` - Clients use only NTLM authentication, and they use NTLMv2 session security if the server supports it. Domain controller accepts LM, NTLM, and NTLMv2 authentication.
>
> `3` - Clients use only NTLMv2 authentication, and they use NTLMv2 session security if the server supports it. Domain controllers accept LM, NTLM, and NTLMv2 authentication.

Source: [How to get Windows to save password for Outlook Anywhere](http://bytesolutions.com/Support/Knowledgebase/KB_Viewer/ArticleId/7/How-to-get-Windows-to-save-password-for-Outlook-Anywhere.aspx)

Comment: I am on Windows 7.  The seems like it's for Windows NT.  Will it work?

Comment: The group policy setting is *from* Windows NT - it's still relevant.

Comment: So just to be sure.  My registry does not have the key that the article says I should change.  Should I just create it?

Comment: Yes, as a DWORD

Comment: Did not work.  I upgraded to Office 2010 and it still does not work.